# How to configure multiple LDAP domain authentication in Apache Server?

Tags: apache, svn, ldap

In configuring SVN using LDAP authentication, I do it in this way:

```
<Location /svn>
   DAV svn
   SVNParentPath /svn
   SVNListParentPath off
   AuthType Basic
   AuthBasicProvider file ldap
   AuthLDAPURL "ldap://123.456.789.10:389/DC=org,dc=huahsin?sAMAccountName?sub"
   ...
   require valid-user
</Location>
```

May I know how could I authenticate users from 2 different domain from 2 different server? Can this be done?

Comment: Off topic, belongs on serverfault.com

Comment: Please help move to serverfault.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes using [mod_authn_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authn_alias.html).  There's an example of such a setup in this other question on severfault.com:
https://serverfault.com/questions/140858/authenticating-apache-httpd-against-multiple-ldap-servers-with-expired-accounts